# Show a custom shipping option when cart item quantity is over 24 items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show a free shipping option (not the standard woocommerce free shipping) provided by a plugin that's hooked up to a delivery service's api when the number of items in the cart reaches above 24.

I found the code below online that basically does what I'm after, only problem is that I need to specify the rendering of shipping options on the shipping method label and not the actual type of shipping method, like below, i.e. "free_shipping".

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'show_hide_free_shipping', 10, 2);
function show_hide_free_shipping($available_shipping_methods, $package){
    $minimum_number_of_item = 24; //Give here minumum number of items to allow freeshipping

    $free_shipping  =   false;
    global $woocommerce;

    $item_count = 0;
    foreach (WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $item) {
        $item_count += $item['quantity'];
    }

    if( $item_count >= $minimum_number_of_item ){
        $free_shipping  =   true;
    }

    if($free_shipping){
        foreach($available_shipping_methods as $shipping_method =>  $method){
            if( strpos( $shipping_method, 'free_shipping' ) === false ) {
                unset($available_shipping_methods[$shipping_method]);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        foreach($available_shipping_methods as $shipping_method =>  $method){
            if( strpos( $shipping_method, 'free_shipping' ) !== false ) {
                unset($available_shipping_methods[$shipping_method]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

I'm far from a php/wordpress wiz so I would deeply appreciate any help I could get.